# how to hide black file background about wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

please see the image first http://libertygroupllc.com/twowindow.jpg

hi, look at this image, if i click the py.exe file which was setted up by py2exe, there are two windows to be showed....  apparently, i don't want the black background (that is python.exe)... so how to hide it so that when i click the py.exe, and only one window will be showed....

thank you ~

---

**to Mark:**

hi, i try that, but it is NOT working...  let me explain more...

i have one test.py file like below:

```
import wx
class gideon(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'This is a new window',size=(500,400))
    panel = wx.Panel(self)

    button = wx.Button(panel,label='Exit',pos=(130,10),size=(60,60))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.closebutton,button)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE,self.closewindow)

    status = self.CreateStatusBar()
    menubar = wx.MenuBar()
    first = wx.Menu()
    second = wx.Menu()
    first.Append(wx.NewId(),'New Window','This is a new window')
    first.Append(wx.NewId(),'Open...','This will open a new window')
    menubar.Append(first,'File')
    menubar.Append(second,'Edit')
    self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

def closebutton(self,event):
    self.Close(True)

def closewindow(self,event):
    self.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = gideon(parent=None,id=-1)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

and setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(
console=["test.pyw"],
options = { "py2exe": { "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll"] } }
)
```

i put this two files on the desktop, and cmd => cd desktop => setup.py py2exe

i can do Unsuccessfully according to your meaning neither test.py nor test.pyw...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename your python file to be a .pyw file.  Doing so will prevent the first command prompt window from displaying.

EDIT:  After your clarification, the problem is in your setup.py file.  You should use 'windows=' instead of 'console='. You can find a more complete list of options that you can use in your setup.py file [here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions).

By using:

```
windows=[ 'test.py' ]
```

you are telling py2exe to build a GUI executable, which should then prevent the command prompt from showing.

Also, you can use 'test.py' as your input as opposed to 'test.pyw'.

Comment: i did that, Thank you Mark so much ! o(∩_∩)o ~